# Add an exclamation mark at the end of strings in a List

Tags: python, arrays, input

So I have a List of strings in Python

```
List=["Hello there", "Nice one"]
```

I wish to add ! in the end of the strings so it becomes like this

```
List=["Hello there!", "Nice one!"]
```

I figured I can iterate through use split() to make them into separate arrays and then append("!") then join this is what I have so far.

```
List=["Hello there", "Nice one"]
for i in List:
    List[i].split()
    List[i].append("!")
    List[i].join()
    print(List(i))
```

can somebody maybe tell me a better way or help me fix this one

Answer (score 4):

Use list comprehension

```
[e+"!" for e in List]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way can be like this:

```
>>> List=["Hello there", "Nice one"]
>>> List_new = [i + '!' for i in List]
>>> List_new
['Hello there!', 'Nice one!']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension and the join method.  And highly recommended you do NOT call your `list` "list"

```
In [1]: data = ["Hello there", "Nice one"]                                      

In [2]: data2 = [''.join([t, '!']) for t in data]                               

In [3]: data2                                                                   
Out[3]: ['Hello there!', 'Nice one!']
```